# Python list of lists from enum

Tags: python, list, enums

here is my example

```
class MyClass(Enum):
    x=[1,3,5]
    y=[2,5,7]
    w=[33,49]
```

I would like to write method that will give me a list of ALL lists from enum. For that example it should return

```
[[1,3,5], [2,5,7], [33,49]]
```

I tried something like this:

```
listWithValues= [ z.value for z in MyClass]
```

But as you can guess it didnt work. Thanks for any helpful advices.

Comment: what does Enum look like?

Comment: Seems to work for me...

Comment: What is `Enum` defined as??

Comment: @chbchb55 probably the `enum.Enum` in the standard library

Comment: One of the issues you're going to run into is that the attributes in a class are stored in a dictionary and don't come out in any specific order.

Comment: "It didn't work" is not specific enough.

Comment: maybe listWithValues= [ x.value for x in MyClass] that is wrong example, I mean I would like to have list with EVERY list from enum

Comment: @Mateusz Can you please edit into your question what exactly "_list with EVERY list from enum_" is? Like the particular list?

Comment: @kindall I think may not be an issue with the way the iterator protocol is defined for `Enum` classes (or I guess, metaclasses). In any event, `MyClass.__members__` should return an ordered mapping.

Comment: looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python?rq=1

Comment: @Mitch now I think it should be easy to understand

Comment: What's __wrong__ with your output, from the provided list comprehension you put in your question?

Comment: @Mateusz no, it isn't, because running *your exact code* is giving the output you say you want. So what output are you getting?

Comment: @kindall in fact, it is [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#creating-an-enum) that "Enumerations support iteration, in definition order".

Comment: Ok my mistake.

I create that listWithValues= [ z.value for z in MyClass] inside class. Outside calss it is working, however I think it is rather not ellegant to store that outside class

Comment: @Mateusz It should hypothetically even work inside the class. You _really_ need to add the __actual error message or problem__ you are having in place of "its not working".

Answer (score 1):

Here is a full example of what you want. This method will always return every list in the enumeration and ignore every other variable.

```
import enum


class MyClass(enum.Enum):
    x = [1, 2, 3]
    y = [4, 5, 6]
    z = "I am not a list"
    w = ["But", "I", "Am"]

    @classmethod
    def get_lists(cls):
        """ Returns all the lists in the Enumeration"""
        new_list = []

        for potential_list in vars(cls).values():  # search for all of MyClass' attributes
            if (isinstance(potential_list, cls)  # filter out the garbage attributes
                    and isinstance(potential_list.value, list)  # only get the list attributes
                    and len(potential_list.value) != 0):  # only get the non-empty lists

                new_list.append(potential_list.value)

        return new_list


print(MyClass.get_lists())
```

Answer (score 0):

From the comments it sounds like you want a method on the class that will return a list of all the values.  Try this:

```
    @classmethod
    def all_values(cls):
        return [m.value for m in cls]
```

and in use:

```
>>> MyClass.all_values()
[[1, 3, 5], [2, 5, 7], [33, 49]]
```